# how to move all files to root directory (to the same level)

Tags: bash, command-line

I have files in one hundred folders (and its subfolders), how do I move them all to the root level folder (removing all folder structures)?

Lets say, from `/music/many_folders_here/and_also_subfolders` to `/music/`?

Comment: try `find /music/ -type f -exec mv {} /music \;`

Comment: What if filenames are not unique across the sub folders?

Comment: adding `-mindepth 2` will prevent trying to move files already at the root (you get an error message for those)